# Se abre el GUI de Git cuando abro una carpeta cualquiera

Tags: git

¡Ayuda! A veces, cuando abro una carpeta cualquiera, se me inicia el GUI de Git. Estoy usando la versión v2.20.1. Ya lo he reinstalado varias veces, y no cambio nada en la instalación... ¿Alguna idea de qué es lo que pueda estar pasando? Agradezco su ayuda c:
P.D: Indicadme si tengo que daros un video o algo como referencia.

Comment: Muy buenas Ricardo, seria interesante saber que cliente GIT estas usando.¿Has mirado en la documentación y reportes de dicho cliente por si es un error conocido? Un saludo

Comment: Yo uso GitHub For Desktop, pero se me abre es la GUI que trae Git por defecto. No se me abre el GitHub For Dektop... De todos modos, si necesitas algún capture o tipo de información adicional, me dices... Y también miré en la documentación, pero no encontré algo parecido a mi error. Gracias de todos modos ^w^

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado. Tenía un problema con el registro de Windows '^w^

El fallo era que me faltaban algunas claves en `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\,` más específicamente en `Directory\Background`, en la que me faltaba la carpeta `shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\\{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}`, y en `Directory\shell`, en donde cambie el valor de (predeterminado) a `none`.