# Problema en Windows con Git Gui

Tags: git

Literal cuando abro una carpeta que esta en el escritorio en vez de abrir x carpeta abro git gui[!
Anteriormente habia encontrado un problema similar de alguien que lo resolvio editando el registro de Windows.
Realmente intente de la misma manera pero no obtuve solucion.

[Se abre el GUI de Git cuando abro una carpeta cualquiera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/242653/se-abre-el-gui-de-git-cuando-abro-una-carpeta-cualquiera)

[Aca el problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SdGo.jpg)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No se entiende bien ni el problema, ni lo que quieres lograr, te invito a reformularlo mejor para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte